# select_tag from hash ruby on rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a hash

```
{"1":"value1","2":"value 2","4":"test"}
```

I want to have a select_tag like this one

```
<select>
<option id="1">value1</option>
<option id="2">value 2</option>
<option id="4">test/option>
</select>
```

I tried

```
select_tag "col", options_from_collection_for_select(col.map { |k,v| [k,v] },:required => true,:include_blank => false)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use *options_for_select*

```
<%= select_tag "col", options_for_select(hash.map { |k,v| [v,k] }, { required: true, include_blank: false}) %>
```

Note that [v, k] inverted to give the correct value and display name